# startActivity in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

this is my code :

```
package gal.doron.ballinthehole;

import android.content.Intent;
public class BallMover extends Thread
{
        private Ball[] balls;
        private Paddle paddle;
        private GameLevels levels;
        private GameView gameview;
        private enum Directions {Top, Right, Bottom, Left, None};
        public BallMover(Ball[] b, Paddle p, GameLevels levels, GameView view)
        {
                this.balls = b;
                this.paddle = p;
                this.levels = levels;
                this.gameview = view;
        }
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
                while(true)
                {
                        if(levels.isFinishLevel())
                        {
                                levels.setCurrentLevel(levels.getCurrentLevel()+1);
                                for(int i=1;i<balls.length;i++)
                                {
                                        balls[i].setVisible(false);
                                        balls[i].restart();
                                }
                                balls[0].restart();
                                try
                                {
                                        sleep(1000);
                                }
                                catch (InterruptedException e)
                                {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++)
                        {
                                if(this.balls[i].isVisible())
                                {
                                        this.balls[i].moveBall();
                                        checkHitPaddle(i);
                                        checkHitBrick(i);
                                }
                        }
                        this.gameview.postInvalidate();
                        try
                        {
                                sleep(1);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
        public void checkHitPaddle(int ballI)
        {
                Ball ball = balls[ballI];
                if(ball.Left()<=paddle.Right() && ball.Right()>=paddle.Left())
                {
                        if(ball.Bottom()>=paddle.Top())
                        {
                                ball.bounceUp();
                        }
                }
                else if(ball.Bottom()>=paddle.Bottom()+10){

                        Intent GameOverScreen = new Intent(BallMover.this, GameOverScreen.class);
                        startActivity(GameOverScreen);
                }
                        //ball.restart();
        }
        public void checkHitBrick(int ballI)
        {
                Ball ball = balls[ballI];
                String direction = getHitBricksDirection(ballI).name();
                if(direction.compareTo("Top")==0)
                        ball.bounceUp();
                if(direction.compareTo("Bottom")==0)
                        ball.bounceDown();
                if(direction.compareTo("Left")==0)
                        ball.bounceLeft();
                if(direction.compareTo("Right")==0)
                        ball.bounceRight();
        }
        public Directions getHitBricksDirection(int ballI)
        {
                Ball ball = balls[ballI];
                Bricks bricks = levels.getLevelBricks();
                Brick brick;
                for(int i=0;i<bricks.rows();i++)
                {
                        for(int j=0;j<bricks.cols();j++)
                        {
                                brick = bricks.getBrick(i, j);
                                if(brick.getType()!=0)
                                {
                                        if(ball.Left()<=brick.Right() && ball.Right()>=brick.Left())
                                        {
                                                if(ball.Bottom()-brick.Top()>=0 && ball.Bottom()-brick.Top()<=1)
                                                {
                                                        brick.ballHitBrick();
                                                        return Directions.Top;
                                                }
                                                if(ball.Top()-brick.Bottom()<=0 && ball.Top()-brick.Bottom()>=-1)
                                                {
                                                        brick.ballHitBrick();
                                                        return Directions.Bottom;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        if(ball.Top()<=brick.Bottom() && ball.Bottom()>=brick.Top())
                                        {
                                                if(ball.Right()-brick.Left()>=0 && ball.Right()-brick.Left()<=1)
                                                {
                                                        brick.ballHitBrick();
                                                        return Directions.Left;
                                                }
                                                if(ball.Left()-brick.Right()<=0 && ball.Left()-brick.Right()>=-1)
                                                {
                                                        brick.ballHitBrick();
                                                        return Directions.Right;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                return Directions.None;
        }
}
```

I wanna make it so that my function will send me to GameOverScreen Activity.

as you can see the problematics lines are

```
Intent GameOverScreen = new Intent(BallMover.this, GameOverScreen.class);
            startActivity(GameOverScreen);
```

I know that BallMover class is Thread and its actually need to be Activity..

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: pass the context to the thread, or use a delegate to ask the activity  to start `GameOverScreen`

Comment: May call your thread class from some activity in order to initiate activity. and pass any context to constructor of your thread,

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `Intent` constructor is any object of `Context` class of any of it's subclasses. So one of the ways to resolve this issue will be to pass a `Context` at the `BallMover` constructor:

```
public BallMover(Ball[] b, Paddle p, GameLevels levels, GameView view, Context context)
    {
            this.balls = b;
            this.paddle = p;
            this.levels = levels;
            this.gameview = view;
            this.context = context;
    }
```

By `Context` you can pass application context, for example. After that you can create `Intent` like the following:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, GameOverScreen.class);
```

Comment: ok... i did it but the line : startActivity(GameOverScreen); cannot work if the class extends Thread and not extends Activity. Right ?

Comment: @user3545490 I've made an edit, you shouldn't call your intent like the class you want to start. And yes, GameOverScreen should be subclass of Activity

Comment: I actually ask about BallMover class. And sorry this edit do not work for me :( . i did exactly like you..

Comment: @user3545490 why it doesn't work? it should. do you get runtime exception or compilation error?